# matplotlib grid setting (python)

Tags: matplotlib, grid

I made some changes of matplotlib settings and can't figure out how to put it back. it would be great if you can help me out!

original settings

[image]

image that i see now

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question lacks relevant information such as exactly what did you change. In any case something like this should solve your problem:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
```

Comment: oh, what I mean by change was that the background color has been changed to white and as a result I could no longer see grid in the graph.

Comment: Those plots seem to be from seaborn so try changing the style for something you like (perhaps "darkgrid": https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/aesthetics.html#temporarily-setting-figure-style).

Comment: armatita, thanks for the reply. the link you gave was the one I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print plt.style.available
```

which will give you the list of available styles on your machine ('classic','seaborn', etc).

From here you can set which existing plot style you want to use with

```
plt.style.use('classic')
```